# Ficus tree leafs with spots, get yellow and fall

Tags: ficus

Hi I´ve a Ficus for many years  without any issues. For some 6 months or so the leafs started getting yellow and fall. [image: spotted leafs]

Answer (score 1):

This is too much water or poor drainage or both.  The soil has less air spaces due to too much water and this promotes the growth of fungus/virus/bacteria which show in the leaves as the spots.  Indicators are:

- shows on older leaves first
- close examination shows a dead spot surrounded by a dying brown ring which is typical of the growth/rest/growth life cyle

Ficus are tough.  Cut the plant back hard, reduce watering, increase light and the plant will bud out new growth and overcome the problem